# how do i do a countdown timer in asp c# using the .aspx.cs file?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, timer, countdown

The code below that I have hides an image after a certain time has elapsed.

```
<div id = "imageDiv">
    <img src="../images/banner.jpg" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function hideImage() {
            var elementRef = document.getElementById("imageDiv");
            elementRef.style.display = 'none';
        }
        function windowOnLoad() {
            var timerInterval = 3000;
            window.setTimeout('hideImage()', timerInterval);
        }

        window.onload = windowOnLoad;

    </script>
```

And, the code below is a count down timer that displays.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function countDown(sec, elem) {
                    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
                    element.innerHTML = "Time left: " + sec + " seconds";
                    if (sec < 1) {
                        clearTimeout(timer); //clear timeout
                        element.innerHTML = 'Time is up!';
                    }
                    sec--;
                    var timer = setTimeout('countDown(' + sec + ', "' + elem + '")', 1000);


                }
    </script>
    <div id="status" style="font-family: 'Segoe UI Light'; color: #FFFFFF"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        countDown(30, "status");
    </script>
```

Is there a way to combine these two javascript functions into one and make it display a imagine after a timer count downs?

Comment: It is possible to do in the .cs file but you need to remember that that is server side, while javascript is client side and is where functionality like that should be placed.
You would still need some client side code running regardless, as some form of AJAX call would be required to know when the timer is expired.

So, in short, you'd need a VERY good reason to bother doing this client side.

Comment: It is because I do not know how to do it with Javascript so I want to try doing it on the .cs file.

Comment: How hard is it to figure out the reverse logic here? Set `style="display:none"` for image. Change method name from `hideImage` to `showImage`. Put code `elementRef.style.display = 'block'` instead of `elementRef.style.display = 'none';`.